# How can I switch/checkout a branch that I created on BitBucket with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I'm just getting started with TortoiseGit and BitBucket, so sorry if this is trivial.  I know I must be missing something simple, but I was unable to locate a previous post that identified this issue.

I performed the following steps:

1. Used the Git Clone command to create a new Git folder (with TortoiseGit)
2. Created a new branch on BitBucket.
3. Attempted to Switch/Checkout the new branch with TortoiseGit.

However, the new branch is not accessible from TortoiseGit.  I see older branches, but not the latest.  I noticed that the new branch appears as a "Merged" branch on BitBucket, as it is still identical to the Master.  Yet, I have access to another branch that is Merged as well.

What am I missing?  Should I use the TortoiseGit "Create Branch" command in the future?

**Addendum** In the dropdown, "master" is selected and then a bunch of "remotes".  The new branch is apparently not included in the "remotes" for some reason.  Is this the issue?

Any ideas at all???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fetch or pull the changes from the remote repository first. Then the remotely created branch will appear in the Switch/Checkout dialog.

With Git all repositories/working trees are (more or less) independent from each other until you fetch/pull/push.